# javascript not working with forloop right?

Tags: javascript, function, date, colors

I'm making a list of events with dates that are converted to how many days there till the event. I want the events to have different colors, further ones being more red and closer one's being greener. days is integer value and I check beforehand if it's null or below 0 then it's 0. For some reason this function is sometimes skipped totally for some of the events..

this getTimeAndColorForElement() is inside loop for each element in a list.

```
function getTimeAndColorForElement(time, element){
  //time can be ISO 8601-format
  var t = Date.parse(time) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );

  if(!days || days < 0){
      days = 0;
  }
  var color = getColor(days);
  $(element).css('color', color);

  //... then sets days, hours mins and so on..

}
```

which calls this function to get the color for it..

```
function getColor(days) {

      var red = 0;
      var green = 250;
      var blue = 0;

      //set color more red the more days there is
      for(i = 0; i < days; i++) {
          green -= 15;
          red += 15;
      }

      //keeping it in 0-255 color values.
      if(green < 0) {
          green = 0;
      }
      if(red < 0) {
          red = 0;
      }
      if(blue < 0) {
          blue = 0;
      }
      if(green > 250) {
          green = 250;
      }
      if(red > 250) {
          red = 250;
      }
      if(blue > 250) {
          blue = 250;
      }

      //color in rgb
      var color = "'rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")'";

      return color;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're initializing your loop variable. `for (var i = 0; ...`. Without it, you're creating a global variable which can lead to weird things like this.

Comment: Why loop when you can simply multiply?

Comment: @MikeC epascarello both work, thanks. Yeah I forgot to initialize the variable doh! MisterSpock's answer is pretty simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just do:

```
var colorStep = 15,
    red       = colorStep * days,
    green     = 250 - colorStep * days,
    blue      = 0;

...
```

Comment: Hey that's actually lot simpler haha :D thanks @MisterSpock